# How to make a navbar floating in tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

This is my code for site-header.

```
export function SiteHeader() {
  return (
    <header className="fixed top-0 z-50 w-full border-b border-border/40 bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
      <div className="container flex h-14 max-w-screen-2xl items-center">
        <MainNav />
        <MobileNav />
        <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-between space-x-2 md:justify-end">
          {/* <div className="w-full flex-1 md:w-auto md:flex-none">
            <CommandMenu />
          </div> */}
          <nav className="flex items-center">
            <Link href="" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
              <div
                className={cn(
                  buttonVariants({
                    variant: "ghost",
                  }),
                  "w-9 px-0"
                )}
              >
                <Icons.discord className="h-4 w-4" />
                <span className="sr-only">Discord</span>
              </div>
            </Link>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

But I don't want to make navbar/header fitting at the top. I want to make the navbar as shown in this site [https://academy.dhruvrathee.com/](https://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `sticky` class instead of `fixed`